# Use CELL on an array to return string made of types of the cells

Tags: excel, formula

Lets say we have 5000 rows with random values (blanks, numbers, characters). I need to show type of all the cells in these 5000 rows in a single cell using a formula. Is it actually possible? I've tried to CONCATENATE(CELL("type";array)) and ctrl+shift+enter but it didn't work (it returns the type of the first cell in the array).
If you want to know, this is for finding a cell with text rather than values or blanks in a very big file. Maybe you have a better solution.
Thanks in advance.

UPD: thanks for macros but I can't use them in this workbook, I need a formula-solution.

UPD: I've got how to do it with conditional formatting => new rule => use a formula to determine... => use ISTEXT('first cell of the range') formula

But still, is it possible to create the formula?

Comment: **5** rows or **5000** rows ?? ............how many columns ??

Comment: sorry, 5000 rows. It actually doesn't matter, the formula will be the same. One column (if it matters)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this is to use MACROs

Here is my sample code:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    numRows = 10 ' Number fo rows to loop through, in your case 5000

    'loop through each cell located in column 1
    'Check its type
    'Concatenate each one in 1 cell on the 8th column
    For i = 1 To numRows
        Sheet1.Cells(1, 8).Value = Sheet1.Cells(1, 8).Value & TypeName(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value) & ","
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of *TypeName (+1)*

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use macro. I need a formula that anybody can copy-paste in their workbook and find wrong formats in the array (not everyone can use macros due to security policies)

Comment: if you look at my attached image, is it exactly that what you wanted?

Comment: @Serg  Would you be willing to use **Conditional Formatting** to hi-light cells with a certain *cell-type* ??

Comment: @Gary's Student it might work but I didn't find a way to do this (didn't find the option in conditional formatting)

Comment: there is an option in conditional formatting where you can add your own equations. Click on: Conditional Formatting > New Rule > "Use a formula to determine  which cells to format.  In "Format values where this formula is true" type:                           =IF(CELL("type",P243)="b",TRUE,FALSE).                                CELL("type" gives only 3 types of outputs "l" = label (a string value), "b" = blank and "v" = value anything else. then you should put a background color for each case. I have 3 formulas each equaling to the the specific letter (l,v,b).

Comment: **IMPORTANT you must remove the $ from the cell reference so that you can use "format Printer" (in home tab) to apply that rule to all 5000 rows. Much quicker than going one by one. As for that 1 specific formula I'll try to keep it in mind.

Comment: Double click on "format painter" to do multiple columns if needed. Then "ESC" to exit

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this small user defined function to your needs.

Say we are looking at cells in the first row, from **A1** through **D1** and we want to concatenate their *types* into a single cell.  Enter the following *UDF()* in a standard module:

```
Public Function KonKaType(rIN As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
        For Each r In rIN
            s = "cell(""type""," & r.Address(0, 0) & ")"
            KonKaType = KonKaType & Evaluate(s)
        Next r
End Function
```

and then in the worksheet cell **E1** enter:

```
=KonKaType(A1:D1)
```

[image]